# How much health does an Apple heal?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

How much HP does an apple heal? Whenever I pick up an apple the amount healed seems to vary. Does the amount healed scale with my character's maximum HP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you got the apple from.

- Apple found in dungeon - heals 20% of maximum HP (rounded down).
- Apple bought from shop - heals 10 HP.

To figure this out I made [a spreadsheet tracking my stats and HP restored when picking up apples](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c5G92fMrT5UKtd3hNjzOkRokh7LRk6vt9oj37RWT9kI/edit?usp=sharing) and tried a few different formulas. Initially I thought the healing amount could be tied to level, but the Warrior's Episode 3 condition of decreasing HP when leveling helped disprove that.

[image: Spreadsheet of Apple healing]